# Ruby Regex not matching what it should be

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got the following regex:

`regex = /\$([a-zA-Z.]+)/`

and the following query

`query = "Show me the PE Ratio for $AAPL, $TSLA"`

Now `regex.match(query)` *should* capture `AAPL` and `TSLA`, but instead I get the following:

`#<MatchData "$AAPL" 1:"AAPL">`

which is completely wrong. Anyone know why?

Note that this regex works fine on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/j0maQHnVFF

Comment: Why do you claim it wrong? It is not wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Ruby` the `.match` method will only return the first capture. You need it to return all captured matches, like the `/g` flag in `PCRE`

You can use the [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) method. The scan method will either give you an array of all the matches or, if you pass it a block, pass each match to the block.

**Code**

```
query.scan(/\$([a-zA-Z.]+)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, needed to use .scan instead of .match

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Doesn't it? It could be expanded upon and better phrased but it is an answer.

Comment: @Kedarnath Sorry, I should have mentioned, I'm the OP